# Extract lines that have two or more dots

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, search

I need to extract (or count) the lines (in a file)
that have two or more dots. The lines should not start with dot
(it’s OK if they *end* with a dot), and there must not be two dots in a row
(i.e., the dots are all separated with non-dot characters).

Output Example:

```
a.b.
a.b.com
a.b.c.
a.b.c.com
```

But not:

```
a.com
a..b
a.b.c..d
```

I did this command:

```
grep -P '^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.)+[.]+' file.txt | wc -l
```

but it didn't find any matching lines. 
How should I do this?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I do not worry. If you mean the `[.]+` what I intend is to say followed b any character whether dot or other. The `.` in RegEx refers to any character. Am I wrong? Can you clarify which part you are talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `\.` and `[.]` are equivalent — they both match a literal dot,
   and not any other character. 
   As a matter of style, pick one and use it consistently.
2. Your problem is that your regular expression (i.e., pattern)
   has `([^.]+\.)+` followed by `[.]+`. 
   That’s really (sort of) equivalent to `[^.]+\.` followed by `[.]`,
   with the result that your grep is looking for lines that contain
   `text.text..`,
   i.e., two dots in a row. 
   If you check, you’ll see that your command
   matches `a.b..`.
3. OK, I believe that the fix is fairly simple:

   ```
   grep -P '^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.)+[^.]*$'
   ```

   I.e., change the `[.]` to `[^.]` (perhaps that’s what you meant originally?),
   change the following `+` to an `*`, and add a `$`. 
   After some number of `text.` groups,
   require/allow any number (zero or more) characters other than dot,
   up to the end of the line.
4. An even simpler approach (easier to understand) would be

   ```
   grep -P '^[^.]+\..*\.' file.txt | grep -v '\.\.'
   ```

   The first `grep` finds lines that begin with a non-dot character
   and include at least two dots. 
   The second `grep` removes lines that have two consecutive dots.
5. Rather than do `grep … | wc -l`, just do `grep -c …`.

Comment: `a.b.c.` is possible but not `a.b..` or `a.b.c..` i.e., no consequent dots comes. Plz, try to do the minimum changes to correct my command rather than coming up with completely new way that needs me to parse and search and understand what it does.

Comment: It would probably be enough to use `-E` here as your regular expressions don't seem to use PCRE expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
.com
.c.c.c.c
a.b.
a.b.com
a.b.c.
a.b.c.com
a.com
a..b
a.b.c..d
```

```
$ awk -F . 'NF > 2 && !/^\./ && !/\.\./' file
a.b.
a.b.com
a.b.c.
a.b.c.com
```

The `awk` program here uses the dot as a field separator. A line having two or more dots is the same as a line having more than two fields.  This is what the `NF > 2` test tests.  The first regular expression discards lines that starts with a dot, and the second regular expression discards lines that contain two dots or more in a row.  The rest of the lines are printed.

The same thing with `grep`:

```
grep '\..*\.' file | grep -v -e '^\.' -e '\.\.'
```

The first expression extracts lines that contain at least two dots, and the two others delete line that start with a dot or contains two consecutive dots.

Or with `sed`,

```
sed -n '/^\./d; /\.\./d; /\..*\./p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with lookarounds, like as shown:

```
$ grep -Pc '^(?!\.)(?!.*\.\..*)(?=.*\..*\.)' file.txt
```

To be read as:

- I am standing at the beginning of the line and looking to my right `^`
- I see the line not begin with a literal dot `(?!\.)`
- On looking further ahead nowhere do I see two consecutive literal dots `(?!.*\.\..*)`
- But I do see two dots, but since consecutive dots were ruled out in my previous lookahead, that means these two dots MUST be separated by at least one non-dot character `(?=.*\..*\.)`
- Q.E.D.